# How to change Bitbucket parent for a fork

Tags: mercurial, fork, bitbucket

I have created a fork of repository A in Bitbucket, and named it repository B1.

Repository A has branch default, branch1 and branch2.

I created a copy of A on my machine that has only branches default and branch1, let's call it A2.

There was an error with my repository and I had to delete repository A (which is the parent for fork B), from Bitbucket, thus leaving fork B without a parent.

I uploaded repository A2 on Bitbucket with the name A.

My question is: How can I make repository A be the parent of fork B, so i can use Bitbucket's sync parent option?

ps: I use mercurial as source control.

Comment: If you make a new fork, then pull from B, would that give you what you want?

Comment: No, because i want B to be a fork for A(now A1), so when i modify A1 i can update the fork B with a click.

Comment: I mean, fork A1, call it B2. Manually pull changesets from B into B2. Won't your B2 sync still be linked to A1? If so, rename B2 to B, and throw B away.

Comment: Can you post your last comment in the form of an answer so i can accept it? That is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Fork A1 call it B2.

Manually pull changesets from B into B2.

Check that B2 is now basically the same as B, but connected to A1 with your one click update.

Use B2 instead of B with optional renaming.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you cannot re-attach a parent to a fork, once the relationship is broken.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i found that out. I found storm's answer to be the next best option in case you need to have the relationship.

Comment: Fair enough. Be aware though that that will merely replicate the repo's code. Pull requests and activity data will not survive such re-creation.